# ¿Cómo se le llama en español a una mesa que se usa al aire libre?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, méxico

[image: picture of a picnic table]

De vez en cuando, la mesa tiene un paraguas para protegerse del sol y la lluvia.

Estas mesas están expuestas a la luz del sol y la lluvia. Las mesas de este tipo, nunca se usan en interiores.

En inglés americano se le llama *picnic table* **(mesa de picnic)**

¿Es en nombre de este tipo de mesa diferente en Mexico y Espana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En español también se llaman **mesa de picnic**,

[image]

<sub>*Fuente [decoandlemon.com](https://decoandlemon.com/muebles-jardin/mesa-picnik?gclid=CjwKCAiA68ebBhB-EiwALVC-NhR6_DOJ4Kl2Dsk53cClXopujNupLT_5XG1mac0OXqY5yipNnIoUeBoCqcMQAvD_BwE)*</sub>

Aunque el nombre genérico de los muebles exteriores es "... de jardín", por lo que generalmente se utiliza **mesa de jardín**

[image]

<sub>*Fuente [leroymerlin](https://www.leroymerlin.es/productos/jardin-y-terraza/muebles-de-jardin/mesas-de-jardin/mesa-de-jardin-de-comedor-de-aurea-neutro-de-90x56-5x90-cm-17388280.html?utm_campaign=LM_Empoderar_AO_SmartShopping_Jardin/Exterior_Generica_Google_Conversion_OMD&gclid=CjwKCAiA68ebBhB-EiwALVC-NqCxaggrgIny4J0EgZygjlaK8KYnlKcGhn1ZaJVLb9K4HCTO72Nf1xoCXHIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

En el norte de méxico les llamamos así exactamente: ***Mesa de picnic*** o también he escuchado que les llaman ***Mesas de campo***

Por la descripción que das, ¿No estás pensando más bien en una ***Palapa***?
Aunque *palapa* se refiere más bien a la estructura con el techo sobre columnas y sin paredes, hay palapas tan pequeñas que parecen sombrillas, y palapas tan grandes que podrías hacer una recepción para una boda en ellas.

Invariablemente hay una mesa bajo la *palapa*.

[image: una pequeña palapa]

o bien;

[image: palapa con varias mesas lista para un banquete]

Comment: Ten en cuenta que solo hay Palapas en México y en República Dominicana (al menos a nivel lingüístico), tocaría buscar un término más amplio